# subdomain value in PHP (nginx)

Tags: php, nginx, subdomain

I have a Nginx webserver (I'm very new at Nginx). This is my Nginx config file:

```
server {
     listen 80;
     listen [::]:80;
     server_name example.com *.example.com;
     return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name example.com *.example.com;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
             deny all;
    }
```

}

I have a DNS-record set to allow wildcard subdomains. My question now is: how can I "catch" the current subdomain in PHP?

For example: if the subdomain is http://demo.example.com, I want to go to
http://example.com?subdomain=demo.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Add the following server to your Nginx. don't forget to restart Nginx service

```
server {
  server_name  demo.example.com;
  rewrite ^(.*)  http://example.com?subdomain=demo;
}
```

**Update**

according to the comment, for dynamic redirection, you should get the subdomain name by regex

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  ~^(?<name>.+)\.example\.com$;
    return      301  http://example.com/?subdomain=$name;
}
```

Also, you can rewrite it  instead of 301 redirects by

```
rewrite ^(.*) http://example.com/?subdomain=$name;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names) for more info.

Comment: thanks, but it needs to be "dynamic". I mean: it's not sure it is "demo", it can be anything.

Answer (score 1):

The host header will already contain the client requested domain. You could just grab that in php

`$domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];`

However, unless you have a wildcard SSL certificate then you are going to have a bad time.

SSL negotiation takes place before any HTTP exchange so if the subdomain and the SSL cert don't agree the connection will fail.

Also, changing the subdomain to a query string is a bad idea:

- You'll lose the ability to configure each subdomain separately within
  Nginx and force lots of redirects and rewrites for every client
  connection.
- Your SEO will suck.
- What will your page links look like?

If I have one.example.com and you have two.example.com the requests will become:

`example.com?subdomain=one`
`example.com?subdomain=two`

Both of those requests are now being handled by the same index page on example.com. Is that really what you want?

Comment: yeah I have a wildcard SSL certificate. And I'm making a website with different categories. Every category has it's own subdomain: https://cat1.example.com, https://cat2.example.com, and so on. I want to be able to just add a category to the database. So I want a script that checks if the subdomain exists in the database. If you have a better idea to do this, please let me know!

Comment: Put every subdomain in its own folder on your filesystem. Personally I would advise you not to do it like this, you are just making work for yourself. and negatively impacting your visitors browsing experience. `example.com/one/` and `example.com/two/` beats `one.example.com` and `two.example.com`

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you for your advice! I'll use your option then!

Comment: If you keep everything on the same domain then you have no issues with CORS etc when trying to share resources like css files, clients browsers will cache your static assets once for all your pages, page loads between categories wont require new SSL negotiations etc etc, it's just better all round